# Permissions for calling Redirect.aspx in root site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a content editor web part in child sites, pointing to a javascript file in Style Library folder in root site.
This javascript file makes a call to:

```
_layouts/15/appredirect.aspx?client_id={*client_id*)&redirect_uri=*redirect_uri*
```

If user has permissions in root site all is working fine. Can I make the redirect call without having permissions on root site?

Answer (score 1):

No, if they don't have root site access, they won't be able to read the JavaScript in the Style Library and thus not redirecting. You'll need to make sure Everyone except external users has read access to the Style Library.

Comment: The problem wasn't the javascript file, it was the use of Redirect.aspx inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!
My solution: I have created a custom Permission Level with the following permissions:

- View application pages.
- View pages.
- Use remote interfaces.
- Open

Groups in child sites are assigned this permission level in root site and script which use Redirect.asp is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You wont be able to do this because root level access (atleast read) is required to access child site.

Comment: You don't necessarily need root level access to visit a subsite